# docker-compose connection between node and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I read a lots of examples about connecting apps with docker, it seems really simple

Im my case I have

```
version: '2'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: infra-mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  service:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3012:3012
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb
```

My connection in node is

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs0&slaveOk=true'
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

I have the following error

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [9d574801e4b4:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 9d574801e4b4 9d574801e4b4:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

I do not understand why the host become `9d574801e4b4`

When I run `ping mongodb` into my container everything is fine

```
PING mongodb (172.21.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from infra-mongodb.app-admin_default (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from infra-mongodb.app-admin_default (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from infra-mongodb.app-admin_default (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
64 bytes from infra-mongodb.app-admin_default (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.216 ms
^C
--- mongodb ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3156ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.088/0.126/0.216/0.053 ms
```

Comment: I think you should use `container_name` instead of `image` name. That should be like: `mongodb://admin:admin@infra-mongodb:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs0&slaveOk=true` No?

Comment: @HardikShah Same issue renaming `container_name ` to `mongodb`

Answer (score 0):

By default mongo listens on localhost only. If it is for local development, simply [bind it to all interfaces](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-bind-ip-all):

```
version: '2'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: infra-mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: --bind_ip_all
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a problem with mongo, the problem is that my node application can not reach Minho because the host provided is not found

Comment: Fair enough. Could you confirm the `const mongoUrl = mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs0&slaveOk=true` line is exactly what you have in your script? I assume it is a typo in the question.

Comment: Yes I forgot the quotes, fixed it

Comment: hmm, how it is `replicaSet=rs0` ? you have a single instance, not a replica set.

Comment: Yes but I have the same image for production, I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049436/docker-compose-connection-between-node-and-mongo/53049758?noredirect=1#answer-53060944

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but the `depends_on` field in Docker Compose only means "this container has to wait until the other one is started." The service inside doesn't necessarily have to be up and running yet. So your application may be starting too quickly. The Mongo server may not be ready to accept connections yet when your app tries to connect. Run `docker-compose up`, wait for it to fail to start, and then run `docker-compose restart service`.

If this fixes it, then you will probably want to make your application retry connecting after some sort of timeout if it fails to connect on start up.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but no, I can connect me with mongochef database in the container but when I am restarting the service container I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '2' 

services:
  nodejs:
    container_name: nodejs
    image: nexus.XXXX.com:8000/${BE_BUILD}
    restart: always
    environment:
       - dbhost=mongo
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: nexus.XXXX.com:8000/doc/docker/proj-mongodb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

And I am successfully able to connect by below URL:

```
const mongoUrl = mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/admin?authSource=admin
```

---

Check below things that can solve the issue:

- Set dbHost name from NodeJS configuration.
- Link mongo container from NodeJS configuration.
- Use container name to connect.
- Check if `authSource` require to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the issue I do not really understand how does it works ...

```
version: '2'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: infra-mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      service-network:
        aliases:
            - localhost
  service:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3012:3012
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb

networks:
  app-admin-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the docker-compose up log but. had similar problem today.
Solved with a small script I have made.
[wait-for-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-for-mongodb-slim)
In your dockerfile add this:

```
RUN npm install -g wait-for-mongodb-slim

## Launch the wait tool and then your application
CMD wait-for-mongo --uri $MONGO_URI --t 2.5 && npm start
```

where --t is the sceonds until it checks again.

and on your compose add the uri as an environment variable:

```
environment:
   MONGO_URI: mongodb://usr:pw@containername:27017/dbname
```